# Web Scraping through Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, selenium

I am using selenium, python, and javascript to extract data from the following link:

```
https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Fortis+Escorts+Heart+Institute+%26+Research+Centre,+Okhla+Road,+Opp+Holy+Family+Hospital,+New+Friends+Colony,+New+Delhi,+Delhi+110025&ludocid=8685206163378021720#lrd=0x390ce4759f47e68d:0x78880cfd492e2558,1
```

When I execute the following script the main window is scrolled and not the pop up window (an ajax window).

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

I want to scroll the pop up window and not the main window.
Any help is appreciated.

For exiting the loop in the main browser window, I am using the following logic:

```
while (num_clicks>=0 and end_doc==0):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(3)
    num_clicks = num_clicks-1
    x = driver.execute_script("return pageYOffset")
    if x==y:
        end_doc = 1
    y = x
```

Is there a way to use a similar logic to exit from the sub window.

Comment: I am facing a challenge in exiting the loop. On a similar site but with the main window and not a pop up window,  I compare the position of the scroll (using pageYOffset) with the position of the scroll after scrolling it. If they are the same, I exit the loop. But in case of pop up window, there does not seem a way to get the pageYOffset (gives result for the main window). I have to use a workaround which does the job but is not very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Scroll into view](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) of the last review in the list, repeat:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/search?q=Fortis+Escorts+Heart+Institute+%26+Research+Centre,+Okhla+Road,+Opp+Holy+Family+Hospital,+New+Friends+Colony,+New+Delhi,+Delhi+110025&ludocid=8685206163378021720#lrd=0x390ce4759f47e68d:0x78880cfd492e2558,1")

while True:  # TODO: decide on when to stop the loop
    reviews = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("._ju")
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", reviews[-1])
```

The code is working for me, but I've left for you to decide on the endless loop exit condition.

Comment: Works great. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I am facing a challenge in exiting the loop. On a similar site but with the main window and not a pop up window,  I compare the position of the scroll (using pageYOffset) with the position of the scroll after scrolling it. If they are the same, I exit the loop. But in case of pop up window, there does not seem a way to get the pageYOffset (gives result for the main window). I have to use a workaround which does the job but is not very efficient.

Comment: @AmitAgarwal okay, could you create a separate question and provide the necessary details? Thank you. Throw a link here please.

Comment: @alexce. cannot post a question. limit reached. I am posting the code in the main question for exiting the loop in the main browser window.